# Add VIRTUAL output to Xorg

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr, opengl, virtual-desktop

I want to create a dummy, virtual output on my Xorg server on current Intel iGPU (on Ubuntu 16.04.2 HWE, with Xorg server version 1.18.4). It is the similiar to Linux Mint 18.2, which one of the `xrandr` output shows the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
...
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
...
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
...
```

In the Linux Mint 18.2, I can turn off the built-in display (`eDP1`) and turn on the `VIRTUAL1` display with any arbitrary mode supported by the X server, attach `x11vnc` to my main display and I'll get a GPU accelerated remote desktop.

But in Ubuntu 16.04.2, that's not the case. The `VIRTUAL*` display doesn't exist at all from `xrandr`. Also, FYI, xrandr's output names is a little bit different on Ubuntu 16.04.2, where every number is prefixed with a `-`. E.g. `eDP1` in Linux Mint becomes `eDP-1` in Ubuntu, `HDMI1` becomes `HDMI-1`, and so on.

So, how to add the virtual output in Xorg/xrandr?

And how come Linux Mint 18.2 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 (which I believe uses the exact same Xorg server, since LM 18.2 is based on Ubuntu, right?) can have a very different xrandr configurations?

Using `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` is not an option, because the virtual output won't be accelerated by GPU.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a `20-intel.conf` file:

`sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

Add the following configuration information into the file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
EndSection
```

This tells the Intel GPU to create 2 virtual displays. You can change the number of `VirtualHeads` to your needs.

Then logout and login. You should see `VIRTUAL1` and `VIRTUAL2` when you run `xrandr`.

Note if you were using the modesetting driver previously (which is the modern default) switching to the intel driver will cause the names of displays to change from, eg, `HDMI-1` or `DP-1` to `HDMI1` or `DP1`.

Comment: And this also changes the xrandr display names to 'HDMI1' and 'eDP1' instead of 'HDMI-1' and 'eDP-1', as expected!

Comment: Doing this removed my `HDMI1` screen from the list of displays as shown by  xrandr. Could be that this interferes with my Nvidia X settings

Comment: Is it any way to do the same thing with an Nvidia GPU instead of the Intel GPU?

Answer (score 5):

In case of black screen on boot with `20-intel.conf`, create a `30-virtscreen.conf` with these contents:

```
# nvidia/nouveau/amdgpu device should be configured first before Intel GPU
Section "Device"
  Identifier "nvidiagpu0"
  Driver     "nvidia" # Because you are using Nvidia proprietary driver. Change to "nouveau" if you are using open source nouveau driver
EndSection

# Then configure intel internal GPU
Section "Device"
  Identifier "intelgpu0"
  Driver     "intel"
  Option     "VirtualHeads" "2"
EndSection
```

I found this solution on the Issues page of the [kbumsik/VirtScreen Github project](https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/issues/16#issuecomment-439669153).

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD 520 on Linux Mint 20 here.

I can see VIRTUAL1 and VIRTUAL2 in xrandr, however, my system initially boots to a blank screen and I also can't see the virtual display(s) in the display manager of Linux Mint.

Editing this to add another way of adding a virtual output that someone else figured out:

https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/issues/16#issuecomment-865128729

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/400499)